# how in batch mode convert video files to webm

Tags: ffmpeg, webm

I have alot of MOV files from the camera.
I want to convert all of them to WebM with same resolution and FPS.

I know, that FFMPEG can be used for that, but not sure, how to use it to process files in batch mode.

Need help, how to do it.

Comment: What platform? Windows or Unix/Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the windows BAT script i am using:

Additional details about parameters can be found here: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

1st line: You need to point to ffmpeg.exe file, which should be already installed on your

2nd line: extension of input files

3rd line: path for input files. UNC paths can't be used

```
set ffm="C:\Program Files\Common Files\DVDVideoSoft\Dll\ffmpeg.exe"
set frmt=*.mov
cd "Y:\Photos_Personal\2012\David Videos\NEW"
for %%f in (%frmt%) do %ffm% -i "%%f" -acodec libvorbis -ac 1 -ab 96k -ar 48000 -b:v 1100k -maxrate 1100k -bufsize 1835k "%%f.WebM"
mkdir old
move %frmt% old\
@echo **********************************
@echo **** Press any key to finish *****
@echo **********************************
pause
```

Comment: Another example of parameters, if you want to rotate video:
for %%f in (%frmt%) do %ffm% -i "%%f" -acodec libvorbis -ac 1 -ab 96k -ar 44100 -b:v 700k -maxrate 800k -bufsize 1835k -vf "transpose=1" "%%f.WebM"